# How can I transfer from a console app written in "go" to another console app?

Tags: go, console-application

I want to write a console application using "go" that will transfer control to another console application.

Here are the steps:

1. run binary app which validates and installs a few things if necessary
2. binary app constructs a command string with options
3. binary app starts process B and exits (a node.js app in my case)
4. Process B runs to completion and sends output to the same console.

**The ONLY step I need is the ability to start a new process and exit, so that is the question here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Golang fork process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027477/golang-fork-process).  In short, there are issues with doing this directly.  You should instead use a non-Go program to start your node.js app.

Answer (score 1):

The [os package](http://golang.org/pkg/os/)  looks like it has the functionality you might need.
The function StartProcess for starting a process and the function (*Process) Kill to exit it.

Answer (score 1):

[`os/exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) might be helpful:

> Package exec runs external commands. It wraps os.StartProcess to make it easier to remap stdin and stdout, connect I/O with pipes, and do other adjustments.

Check out the [`Cmd.Start` example](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Start).