# Chroot for multiple SFTP clients in golang

Tags: go, ssh, sftp, chroot, isolation

I use Golang as SFTP server for my application and I would like to isolate my clients with a different root directory.

This application allows multiple client connection but I would like to serve  custom root directory for each clients (for better isolation).

In golang I tried to fork the process but it does not seem to be possible: [Fork a go process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370646/how-do-i-fork-a-go-process)

I have tried `syscall.Chroot` into a goroutine but the all binary is being chrooted... In the meantime, this prevent other clients from using the service as the binary is chrooted by the current user.

If you have a possible solution for my problem, I would be very happy to read you.

```
func main() {
    if listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%d", sshServer.Port)); err == nil {
        for {
           if nConn, err := listener.Accept(); err == nil {
                // ...
                if sshConn, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewServerConn(nConn, &sshServer.Config); err == nil {
                    // ...
                    // Accept all channels
                    go handleChannels(chans)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
func handleChannels(chans <-chan ssh.NewChannel) {
    // Service the incoming Channel channel.
    for newChannel := range chans {
        // ...
        if err := syscall.Chroot(chrootPath); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        if err := os.Chdir("/"); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        channel, requests, errChannel := newChannel.Accept()
        if err := server.Serve(); err == io.EOF {
            server.Close()
        }
    }
}
```

Libs used:

- golang.org/x/crypto/ssh
- github.com/pkg/sftp

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the body of the question.

Comment: You can't fork or chroot the main process, so that leaves you with the option of running the sftp server in a subprocess.

Comment: How I can run sftp in a subprocess, and run ssh server on main process?

The sftp protocol relies on ssh channel. I have tried to forward ssh channel in a subprocess and it does not seem to work fine.

Comment: I would say replacing toLocalPath function defined in request-unix.go would be quite straight.