# Detach Goroutine into Independent Process

Tags: go

I have a function that plays a sound that I want to continue executing after my `main` program prints to standard output and exits. My reasoning is that I want the sound to finish playing after the program has exited but I don't want the `main` program to wait for the sound to finish playing before it exits.

I found a method for executing the sound in an independent process by turning it into an executable named `playsound` and doing `go install`. Then in my main program, I call this at the end of `main()`:

```golang
func startPlaySound() {
    cmd := exec.Command("playsound")
    cmd.Start()
}

main() {
   // code that prints and exits

   startPlaySound()
}
```

This works but I would like to be able to play the sound after the main program exits without creating an executable file. I would rather run the equivalent of `cmd.Start()` on the function containing the code to play the sound.

In other words, I would like it to look something like this:

```
func playSound() {
    // code that plays the sound
}

func startPlaySound() {
   cmd := CmdFromFunction(playSound)
   cmd.Start()
}

main() {
   // code that prints and exits

   startPlaySound()
}
```

Does something like `CmdFromFunction` exist?

## Response to Question Feedback

- This is not a duplicate of [How do I fork a go process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370646/how-do-i-fork-a-go-process). I am not trying to fork the `main` goroutine. I am trying to detach `playSound` into a separate process that will continue executing after the `main` goroutine exits. Both of the answers to that question involve executing an external program, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.
- "go routines are not meant to be processes" - I literally turned the code from `playSound` into an executable called `playsound` and am now executing it as a process using `cmd.Start()`. I'm just trying to find a more direct route for doing that than creating an entirely separate executable file.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `exec` runs external executables, so whatever you want to run has to be an external executable. A function in your program can't be run after your program exits, by definition.

Comment: "When that function invocation [main] returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete." https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution

Comment: I understand that. My question is how to transform a goroutine into a full fledged process. It seems like a mechanism that should exist.

Comment: go routines are not meant to be processes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fork a go process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370646/how-do-i-fork-a-go-process)

Answer (score 0):

> GO routines are not meant to be processes

[This](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/) might work. I have done this myself, But you might be restricted to bash shell.

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "playsound", "&")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is already accomplished by the first block of code in my question that calls `cmd.Start()`. What I want is to execute the code in `playsound` without having to have create a separate executable called `playsound` in the first place.

Comment: Down vote and leave a comment why. I hope its not you @ChrisRedford