# Can you run an independent instance of a program from within Go?

Tags: linux, go, concurrency, konsole

I am looking for a way to launch a completely independent instance of a program from within a Go program. So far this is my best attempt:

```
  // Some code   

    go exec.Command("konsole", "--hold", "--separate", "sh", "-e", "go", "run", "test.go")
.Run()

    // Continue doing something else then quit
```

Using linux KDE's Konsole. This command "almost" works - it starts a new Konsole instance and runs the program. But they are dependent: if the first program is ended (ctrl+c), the second also ends. Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the child process (really the child of the child of the child process) being a Go program.

Comment: @Adrian fair enough, I changed it to just program.

Comment: A program running in the background, independent from the one it was started from and with its output streams closed or redirected to a logfile is called "daemon". Running a process as daemon is not just a single call, but these keywords should give you a hint. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027477/how-to-fork-a-process would help.

Comment: If Ctrl-C is the main issue, you can just put it in a different process group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve it you need to replace `exec.Command` call with [`os.StartProcess`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#StartProcess) giving extra process attributes [`os.ProcAttr`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ProcAttr) and [`syscall.SysProcAttr`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SysProcAttr). Setting flag `Setpgid` and leaving `Pgid` with default value of 0 achieves to goal as mentioned by @that_other_guy.

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
        "syscall"
)

func main() {
        cmd, err := exec.LookPath("sleep")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        attr := &os.ProcAttr{
                Sys: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
                        Setpgid: true,
                },
        }
        process, err := os.StartProcess(cmd, []string{cmd, "1m"}, attr)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(process.Pid)
        process.Release()
        for {
        }
        return
}
```